# how does pointer works when moving on array of integers

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, int

I have a question about following code. line 1 can be rewrite as *(p++) = *(p++)+123;
right hand side is 6+123 = 129 that i understand. But how does it assign to left hand side ?
what does *(p++) works as left hand side ? thanks!

```
    int a[] = {6,7,8,9,10};
    int *p = a;
    *(p++)+=123; //array 129 7 8 9 10     line 1  
    cout<<*p<<endl;// 7

    *(++p)+=123;// array 129 7 131 9 10   line 2
    cout<<*p<<endl;// 131
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> line 1 can be rewrite as `*(p++) = *(p++)+123;`

No it can't; that would increment `p` twice. It could be (approximately) rewritten as

```
int & r = *p++;
r = r + 123;
```

while line 2 is more like

```
++p;
*p = *p + 123;
```

> But how does it assign to left hand side ? what does *(p++) works as left hand side ?

`p++` evaluates to a temporary holding the old value of `p`. `*(p++)` dereferences that to give an assignable *lvalue* referring to the object `p` used to point to. `+=` modifies that object.

(NOTE: I'm writing about C++, although you seem to be asking about two different languages. The answer is probably very similar for C, although some of the standard terminology might differ. In future, please decide which language you're asking about.)

Comment: But isn't that for every a+=b is equal to a = a+b ?
or there are rule of += ? some document ?

Comment: @user2879534: `a+=b` is equivalent to `a=a+b` except that `a` is only evaluated once.

Answer (score 1):

This is just very shortened code. Here is a longer version:

```
int a[] = {6,7,8,9,10};
int *p = a;
*p += 123; //array 129 7 8 9 10     line 1  
p++; // p points to a + 1
cout << *p << endl;// 7

++p; // p points to p + 1 = a + 2
*p += 123;// array 129 7 131 9 10   line 2
cout << *p << endl;// 131
```

Essentially: `p++` means return `p` and increment it after, while `++p` means increment it first and return the result.

Answer (score 1):

after executing

```
int a[] = {6,7,8,9,10};
int *p = a;
```

you have something like this in your memory

```
  -------------------- 
 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
  -------------------- 
   |
   a,p
```

then you reach this line: `*(p++)+=123;`
here the increment operator is a post increment, meaning you will use the current value of `p` and increment after.
so we can write this statement as two statements, this first one is: 
`(*p) +=123;`
so we get this in memory

```
  ----------------------
 | 129 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
  ---------------------- 
   |
   a,p
```

and the second statement is incrementing the `p`
`p++;` 
and you get this in memory

```
  ----------------------
 | 129 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
  ---------------------- 
   |     |
   a     p
```

now for line 2: `*(++p)+=123;`
here the increment happens first, and then you dereference the pointer (with its new value) and assign it.
so this statement can be again written as two statements, the first is:
`++p;` 
and you get this in memory

```
  ----------------------
 | 129 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
  ---------------------- 
   |         |
   a         p
```

and the second statement is
`(*p) += 123; // p is pointing at 8,`
and you get this in memory

```
  ------------------------
 | 129 | 7 | 131 | 9 | 10 |
  ------------------------ 
   |         |
   a         p
```

I hope this helps.